# Creating own carousel with a left and right arrow

Tags: html, css

I want to give the similar effect of left and right arrow as shown in the site

This site has an image and it has two arrows. the arrows are having a transition effect but it is hiding when it goes out of the boundary of image.

http://hilary-beautytemplates.blogspot.com/

When I try to do the same thing the left and right arrows are not hiding outside the boundary of image. I am stuck I would like to have the similar effect as this site left and right arrow has.

here is the code

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: green;
}

.imageslider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.source {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: -60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  color: white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.imageslider:hover .left {
  left: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.imageslider:hover .right {
  right: 40px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flexcheck {
  display: flex;
}

.test1 {
  flex: 80%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.test {
  flex: 20%;
  border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcheck">
  <div class="test1">
    <div class="imageslider">
      <div class="source">
        <img src="berth.jpg" class="image">
      </div>
      <!--<div class="source">
                    <img src="apartment.jpg" class="image2">
                </div> -->
      <span class="left"><i class="fa-solid fa-less-than"></i></span>
      <span class="right"><i class="fa-solid fa-greater-than"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test" style="background: aqua;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @mplungjan. I have no idea how this run code snippet automatically gets added when you edited my question. this behaviour is very good you don't have to write again the ouput is displayed. When you post the question does it automatically come or we need to do something to bring this up

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this after a lot of thinking. I applied in the parent container .imageslider by giving overflow:hidden

```
<style>
.imageslider{
overflow: hidden;
}
```

hola and it worked